# Should strictly versioned WCF service namespaces be unique to the contract?

Tags: wcf, web-services, versioning

I am specifying a `Name` and a `Namespace` for every contract in my WCF services, as outlined in Microsoft's [Service Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx) guidelines. However, in their example for each contract, `Namespace` is always suffixed with the `Name` value, like so:

```
[DataContract(
Name = "PurchaseOrder",
Namespace = "http://examples.microsoft.com/WCF/2005/10/PurchaseOrder")]
public class PurchaseOrderV1 : IPurchaseOrderV1
{
    [DataMember(...)]
    public string OrderId {...}
    [DataMember(...)]
    public string CustomerId {...}
}
```

Why is **PurchaseOrder** suffixed on the `Namespace`? Isn't this redundant? Shouldn't the `Namespace` be reflective of the whole immutable contract?

If I want my `DataContracts` and `ServiceContracts` to be strictly versioned together, shouldn't the `Namespace` value be **http://examples.microsoft.com/WCF/2005/10/** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is natural.

http://examples.microsoft.com/WCF/2005/10/ defines a general product-version-like value. In the same way that you have more fine grained namespaces in your C# code, you would do the same with WCF namespaces.

At the end of the day, namespace is just a namespace and this kind of naming **just a convention**.